# Getting facebook video views of the user timeline videos with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Hi i am trying to get the Facebook video views (Videos)uploaded by user to his timeline using Facebook graph api.

I am in the Facebook graph api explorer in my access token i also have permissions for **user_videos** and **read_insights** 
My request for getting the total video views count is this.

```
879235328905006/video_insights/total_video_views/lifetime
```

but when i make the request it gives me empty response every time in the explorer

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

**879235328905006** is my video id which i have uploaded to my timeline and i am also the owner of the video.

I have tried this request with my different video ids but still it gives me empty response.

is their a way we can get the views count of the videos uploaded by the user to his timeline using facebook graph api...?

Comment: insights are only available for pages, i doubt that you can get the info. what for would you need the views anyway? what´s the use case?

Comment: The use case is this User can upload video to his timeline from our website and we want to show the total number of views of video in our website using facebook graph api.

Comment: @luschn with over above use case do you think we can get the number of video views using facebook graph api...?

Comment: no, as i commented, insights are not available for user profiles.